# How to delete backup files (with tilde as the last character) recursively from a folder generated by Quanta Plus?

Tags: backup, file-management, ubuntu-9.04

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 and I use Quanta Plus for programming, but when I try to upload all folders to a server, all of the back up files (which have a tilde as the last character) are also uploaded.

I want to know is there any command by which I can recursively delete all of the backup files from a folder. Please provide a command for me, because it is not possible to delete each and every file manually.

Comment: I have a script which does just this, I am trying to find it but I believe its on my work desktop.  You call it with a path and a constraint to look for.  In your case you could do "./script.sh /path/to/folder/ *~ and it will remove all of your backup files containing the ~ on the end.  Would you be interested in me posting it?

Answer (score 7):

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*~" -delete
```

or

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*~" -ok rm {} \;
```

to prompt before removal

Comment: How would you exclude a directory with this method? The man page for find says: "Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together."

Comment: @Shawn: Something like this (untested): `find /path/to/dir -wholename './subdir/to/skip' -prune -o -name '*~' -ok rm {} \;` You could use `-exec` instead of `-ok` if you don't need to confirm deletions (or you could use `-i` with `rm` as a different way of confirming).

Comment: Thanks Dennis. If others are having problems, note that removing the leading period or adding a trailing slash to './subdir/to/skip' will break the script

Answer (score 1):

For a more graphical solution (and for backing up all those *~ files before you delete them), you could use **gnome-search-tool**

Leave "Name contains:" empty, select your folder, check the 'more' options: "Show hidden and backup files" + "Exclude other filesystems" (to prevent it from searching SSH servers, mounted Ftp folders and connected drives), and then for the magic bit, choose the 'more' option "Name matches regular expression:" and type in

```
^.*~$
```

Then after it's done searching you simply select which ones to remove, right-click and select "Move to Trash". 
I do it this way so I can backup all those files before permanently deleting them.
I uploaded a screenshot here: "dl . elundmark . se / e / Selection-20120114-01 . jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ cd the_folder
$ rm -i `find -name '*~'`
```

The `-i` option prompts before every removal, you can remove it if you're sure.

Comment: That will fail for filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: @Dennis: You've right!